# Rewrite the URL of a deleted post in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, url, permalinks

In a Wordpress blog, a post with a lot of visits got deleted. I can write a new one but I want to reuse the old URL, because people saved the link.

However the permalinks are based on `ID+name_of_post` and I can't create a new post with the same `ID`. I also can't make a redirection because Wordpress considers my old post non-existent.

And of course, my post isn't in the trash.

How to do this?

Comment: Your post isn't in the trash and you can't use the old URL? That is not true or a miracle.

Answer (score 0):

you have to make an update query to database with the old values of post with reference to ID or you can use the backup of db if you have .